# $(window).on('load' isn't working - I want to add a button to html on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to add a start button via jquery to appear when the page loads. However, the button is not loading.

Here is my code:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  const startPage = $("<button id='start'>Go</button>");
  $('main').append(startPage);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Quiz</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Objective London Quiz</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="questions"></main>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't See any problem it loads just fine for me if it doesn't share screenshots

Comment: Try changing the `const startPage = $("<button id='start'>Go</button>");
  $('main').append(startPage);` to`$('main').append(<button id='start'>Go</button>);`

Comment: Its possible that there is some logic which brings in the data for the main tag and your button gets overwritten by it.

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer thank you for letting me know! I restarted everything and tried it and it is indeed functional code! Thanks again.